# How to type Unicode characters such as ✓ U+2713 in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can a Unicode character such as `U+2713  CHECK MARK` be typed in Excel in Office 365, on Windows 10?

These methods all work in Word, but not in Excel:

- holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing `10003` on the numeric keypad produces (in Excel gives ‼ `U+203C DOUBLE EXCLAMATION MARK`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`010003` (nothing in Excel)
- `2713` then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (nothing in Excel)

Excel's help for ‘Insert a check mark’ gives instructions for inserting a Wingdings character which looks like a tick but is actually a ü character (`U+00FC`).

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the link. Could you more specific? So far as I can see, that document just says to do the things I've already tried and mentioned in the question. Is there something else in there I should try? Ta.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are trying to type the
[Unicode Character 'CHECK MARK' (U+2713)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm) : ✓

The documentation here is not very helpful.
The way to do that is to type:

<kbd>Alt down</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> 2713 <kbd>Alt up</kbd>

You need to use the NumPad while typing the <kbd>+</kbd> and the numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately `Alt`+`+` codes only work with a [registry tweak](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/08/17/three-ways-to-enter-unicode-characters-in-windows/). I'm trying to document for colleagues how to type these characters, and I can't rely on that registry setting being set; it isn't by default on this workstation.

Comment: A low-tech suggestion : Create a document with these characters and distribute it for doing copy-paste.

Comment: Yeah, it might come to that! Currently I've emailed one user a selection of ✓, ✔, , and  to copy. I was hoping to find out how to do this properly, so we wouldn't have to.

Comment: @Smylers You could distribute a `.reg` file which accomplishes the registry tweak in a few lines. See this [Microsoft Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310516/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg). V5.00 works for Windows 10. BTW, the article your refer to in your comments puts the tweak in a spot different from other articles I've read.

Comment: Thanks, @RonRosenfeld. “Run this strange file and then reboot” isn't a great answer when somebody just asks how to type a particular character, but I agree if we did get that in the configuration round here it would help.

Comment: The low tech suggestion worked for me. Open Word use Insert>Symbol>More symbols and the character map is displayed. Segoe UI Symbol Subset Dingbats 2743. Copy and paste into Excel.